# preg_match remove unwanted text from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to remove unwanted text from string.

```
$description = 'this is some huge text <a href="http://example.com/dynamicID">dynamicID</a><br> and some more text here';

preg_match('/(example.com([^&]*)?)"/',$description,$matches);

$part = $matches[1];

echo $part; //returning example.com/dynamicID">dynamicID</a><br> and...
```

But i want only ( example.com/dynamicID ) and remove the rest of the text from string.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Non reproducible. https://eval.in/614467 I suspect `$description` is different then provided.

Comment: Yes its different than provided because `$description` is dynamic and different in all the times, but example.com/dynamicID is the focus to extract

Comment: change `(example.com([^&]*)?)` to `(example.com([^"]*)?)`  Replace `[^&]` with `[^"]`  As there is no `&` but there is a `"`  see: https://regex101.com/r/cG9kS3/1

Comment: Thanks man @ArtisiticPhoenix thumbs up for you its working fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. I assume you want to take the URL portion of the text (a.k.a before the closing quote on `<a>` tag.

All you have to do is to add `?"` after `)` to ensure that you try to match as shortly as possible any characters before quote.

Doing that, however, the resulting $matches[0] will also include the quote character. You can remedy this by adding group to what you actually want to match and take $matches[1] as your result. Below is your code modified with the 2 changes I mentioned above:

```
$description = 'this is some huge text <a href="http://example.com/dynamicID">dynamicID</a><br> and some more text here';

preg_match('/(example.com([^&]*)?)"/',$description,$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

The output is like below:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "example.com/dynamicID""
  [1]=>
  string(21) "example.com/dynamicID"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "/dynamicID"
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question according to your suggestion but its still the same result

Comment: I just tried copy paste the code in your question and run it, it works for me. Try `var_dump($matches)` to see what you actually get.

Comment: ok I am getting this using `var_dump($matches)` results `array(3) { [0]=> string(3274) "example.come/dynamicID" dynamicID</a><br> and...`

Comment: `var_dump` returns array of 3. There should be $output[1]. I tried running your updated code in online PHP and it does work: http://ideone.com/ltcW6d

Comment: A thought just came to my mind. If you run it as web (instead of CLI), you may be seeing the cached code. Try restart your server.

Comment: I have restarted my USB Webserver but results the same